# Processing a excel file in node.js server

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an endpoint setup in EC2 nano, the endpoint mainly gets and extracts relevant data from my Mongodb, converts it to an Excel file, and responds with a URL to said Excel file.

The problem I am facing now is that if I get a large amount of data from my Mongodb the server crashes with a response of 502. A quick fix that I could think of was to change the server to EC2 macro but that would be a temporary fix.

Is there a better way to handle this type of processing given that upgrading the server isn't a possibility?

I've tried using ETL and Kafka to send the data in chunks to process but I couldn't figure out how exactly to implement the workflow.

Comment: Could you show an error in your console or log in cloudwatch?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the same processing capacity you have indeed to cap the maximum amount of data the server will process at a given time. Usually a good API introduces pagination. Your query to MongoDB always returns the same number of rows and accepts an offset as input so you can browse data page by page.

You could also implement the transformation in the background as you suggested so you don't translate data into Excel over and over. You could use AWS Batch or AWS Glue and schedule a regular transformation. You will have the same capacity questions though (ie. size correctly your task or job to handle the maximum scenario or paginate one way or another).

Comment: The api itself has pagination thats not the issue, the server crashes when I for example try to make a excel file for all the documents in the mongodb collection. For a smaller number of documents it work fine.

Comment: Well just my point, why don't you limit your process to a smaller number of documents, and give a way to tell which ones?